# I would like to validate this format "DM123456"

Tags: regex

Maximum 8 characters = 2 Alphabets (D,M) and 6 digits (0-9)

So i have a string field which needs to starts with the Uppercase DM and then followed by 6 digits.

Apart from the Alphabets 'D', 'M' it should not accept any other alphabets. It should accept 6 numbers as well

I am trying with the below regular expression but it is not working fine. Kindly please advise the possible solutions.

\^([DM]{2}0-9{6})$\

Comment: Fixing typos: `/^DM[0-9]{6}$/`

Comment: Did you just forget the `[]` around `0-9`?

Comment: It worked fine :)Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew